# Каким образом можно распараллелить алгоритм?

Tags: gpu, matlab

Добрый день, форумчане.

Каким образом можно распараллелить этот алгоритм? Нужно использовать GPU вычисления. А в идеале запустить в несколько потоков. 
Ну мне хотя бы понять, как увеличить скорость расчёта за счет распараллеливания.

```
startStockPrice   = 100;    % Stock price starts at $100.
strike = 95;               % Strike price for the option ($).
barrier = 150;              % Barrier price for the option ($).
riskFreeRate = 0.005;        % 0.5 annual percent. 
timeToExpiry = 2;           % Lifetime of the option in years.
volatility   = 0.20;         % 20% annual volatility. 
M=1e7;
Start = cputime; % time
if startStockPrice < barrier
    final_vals=startStockPrice*exp((riskFreeRate - 0.5*volatility^2)*timeToExpiry + volatility*sqrt(timeToExpiry)*randn(M,1));
end    
if startStockPrice < barrier
    option_values=max(strike-final_vals,0); % Evaluate the Put option options
    present_vals=exp(-riskFreeRate*timeToExpiry)*option_values; % Discount under r-n assumption
else
    % Hit the barrier, so the option is withdrawn.
    present_vals = 0;
end
put_value=mean(present_vals); % Take the average
display(put_value)
Elapsed = cputime - Start   %Measure the execution time
```